# Third party libraries not initializing correctly

Tags: swipe, swiper.js, mithril.js

I have a slider menu that I need to initialize after render to make a menu a slider, but it never initializes correctly.

```
return <div id='drawer' style={cfg.state.displayDrawer() ? 'display:block' : 'display:none'}
        config={(el, isInitialized) => {
            if(!isInitialized) {
                new Swiper('#menu', {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                    centeredSlides: true,
                    paginationClickable: true,
                    spaceBetween: 30
                });
            }
        }}>
        <div id='menu' class='swiper-container'>
            <div class='swiper-wrapper'>
                {ctrl.items().map((item, idx) => {
                    return <div class='swiper-slide'>
                        {console.log(item.name())}
                        {item.name()}
                    </div>
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='content'>
            {m.component(ctrl.content)}
        </div>
    </div>
```

It runs at the right time, but whatever is happening inside Mithril (I can only assume) does not allow this to initialize it correctly. If I run this bit of code below in the console, then the menu initializes perfectly fine.

```
new Swiper('#menu', {
     slidesPerView: 4,
     centeredSlides: true,
     paginationClickable: true,
     spaceBetween: 30
});
```

Comment: It might be that you need to place the `if(!isInitialized) new Swiper ...` bit inside the `#menu` element, instead of its parent

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code in action, it's difficult to imagine what might be causing the problem. I tried replicating [the first demo from the Swiper site](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/01-default.html) using Mithril and couldn't get that to work in a way that felt right - getting the slider to initialise as part of Mithril's `config` and manually initialising it produced the same awkward results. This suggests to me that there aren't any fundamental issues with using Mithril & Swiper together (although I would introduce an `onunload` hook in the `ctrl` or the `config` to ensure the Swiper instance is destroyed at the right time). Can you produce a reduced test case that demonstrates the problem you're having?

```js
m.mount( document.body, {
  controller : function(){
    this.autoInit   = false

    this.items      = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    this.target     = undefined

    this.initSwiper = () =>
      this.swiper = new Swiper( this.target )

    this.onunload   = () => {
      if( this.swiper )
        this.swiper.destroy()
    }
  },

  view : ctrl => [
    m( '.swiper-container', {
      config : ( el, isInitialized ) => {
        ctrl.target = el

        if( ctrl.autoInit && !isInitialized )
          ctrl.initSwiper()
      }
    },
      m( '.swiper-wrapper',
        m( '.swiper-wrapper',
          ctrl.items.map( number =>
            m( '.swiper-slide',
              'Slide ' + number
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ),

    m( '.controls',
      m( 'label',
        m( 'input[type=checkbox]', {
          checked  : ctrl.autoInit,
          onchange : e => 
            ctrl.autoInit = e.target.checked
        } ),

        `Auto-initialise Swiper with Mithril's config`
      ),
      
      m( 'button', {
        onclick : () =>
          m.redraw.strategy( 'all' )
      }, 
        'Mithril reinit'
      ),

      m( 'button', {
        onclick : () =>
          ctrl.initSwiper()
      }, 
        'Initialise Swiper'
      )
    )
  ]
} )
```

```css
.controls {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.controls > * {
  padding: .5em;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;


  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}



/**/
/**
 * Swiper 3.3.1
 * Most modern mobile touch slider and framework with hardware accelerated transitions
 * 
 * http://www.idangero.us/swiper/
 * 
 * Copyright 2016, Vladimir Kharlampidi
 * The iDangero.us
 * http://www.idangero.us/
 * 
 * Licensed under MIT
 * 
 * Released on: February 7, 2016
 */
.swiper-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Fix of Webkit flickering */
  z-index: 1;
}
.swiper-container-no-flexbox .swiper-slide {
  float: left;
}
.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.swiper-container-android .swiper-slide,
.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
}
.swiper-container-multirow > .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.swiper-container-free-mode > .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper-slide {
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/* Auto Height */
.swiper-container-autoheight,
.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-slide {
  height: auto;
}
.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, height;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
  transition-property: transform, height;
}
/* a11y */
.swiper-container .swiper-notification {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
}
/* IE10 Windows Phone 8 Fixes */
.swiper-wp8-horizontal {
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
}
.swiper-wp8-vertical {
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
  touch-action: pan-x;
}
/* Arrows */
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 27px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-background-size: 27px 44px;
  -webkit-background-size: 27px 44px;
  background-size: 27px 44px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled,
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled {
  opacity: 0.35;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  left: 10px;
  right: auto;
}
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23000000'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-white,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23000000'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-white {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
/* Pagination Styles */
.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms;
  -moz-transition: 300ms;
  -o-transition: 300ms;
  transition: 300ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 10;
}
.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* Common Styles */
.swiper-pagination-fraction,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Bullets */
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
button.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: #fff;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #007aff;
}
.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #fff;
}
.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #000;
}
.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-pagination-bullets {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0);
}
.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: block;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
/* Progress */
.swiper-pagination-progress {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
}
.swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #007aff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
  -moz-transform-origin: right top;
  -ms-transform-origin: right top;
  -o-transform-origin: right top;
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-pagination-progress {
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-white {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #fff;
}
.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #000;
}
/* 3D Container */
.swiper-container-3d {
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  -o-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
}
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-wrapper,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-cube-shadow {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  /* Safari 4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+, iOS 5+ */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Firefox 16+, IE10, Opera 12.50+ */
}
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  /* Safari 4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+, iOS 5+ */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Firefox 16+, IE10, Opera 12.50+ */
}
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  /* Safari 4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+, iOS 5+ */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Firefox 16+, IE10, Opera 12.50+ */
}
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  /* Safari 4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+, iOS 5+ */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Firefox 16+, IE10, Opera 12.50+ */
}
/* Coverflow */
.swiper-container-coverflow .swiper-wrapper,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-wrapper {
  /* Windows 8 IE 10 fix */
  -ms-perspective: 1200px;
}
/* Cube + Flip */
.swiper-container-cube,
.swiper-container-flip {
  overflow: visible;
}
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/* Cube */
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-container-cube.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-next,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-prev,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-next + .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-cube-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
  filter: blur(50px);
  z-index: 0;
}
/* Fade */
.swiper-container-fade.swiper-container-free-mode .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
/* Scrollbar */
.swiper-scrollbar {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 3px;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 5px;
  width: 98%;
}
.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 1%;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 5px;
  height: 98%;
}
.swiper-scrollbar-drag {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.swiper-scrollbar-cursor-drag {
  cursor: move;
}
/* Preloader */
.swiper-lazy-preloader {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
  -moz-animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
  animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
}
.swiper-lazy-preloader:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%236c6c6c'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-position: 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.swiper-lazy-preloader-white:after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%23fff'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
@-webkit-keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/lhorie/mithril.js/next/mithril.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have two `.swiper-wrappers` if that makes any difference. And I actually got it to initialize by having it run if `cfg.state.displayDrawer()` is `true` as opposed to checking `isInitialized`. Though if it's not inside a `div` that is hidden, then it works just fine. It's hard to give a plunker because it's dependent on a lot of specific data. Sorry I can't be more specific with the example. I also can't seem to get your snippet to work as it doesn't seem to be recognizing Mithril.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (am guessing) the `#menu` element hasn't been created by the time the first config runs, a simple way to test this hypothesis could be to add a `console.log('menu exists: ' + !!document.getElementById('menu'))` as the first line of the config function.

Personally, I've tackled equivalent situations by creating a `prop` to track the element I'm trying to target, and then calling the config function again with a setTimeout/requestAnimationFrame if the element isn't ready yet. (I've also infinite looped myself as well, so maybe be a tad cautious :-p )

I prefer to use a prop rather than accessing the dom directly.

I also like using the `ctx.swiper = new Swiper...` style to facilitate adding an `onunload` cleanup function.

Fiddle example (ish, I had to hack together fake content and props, and had to convert the msx syntax) here: https://jsfiddle.net/98p3wptf/5/

(Afaict it's working because I can swipe the `something` and `something2`? (I don't know anything about Swiper.))